# Using a MiFi via WDS

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, wds, mifi

I have a [Huawei R201](http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/productFeatures.do?pinfoId=2690&directoryId=5009&treeId=3619) MiFi connected to the internet, and I'd like to use its internet connection even from devices that **don't** have WiFi, so I grabbed a [wireless router](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-MR3220) I had lying around and configured WDS so that it'd connect to the MiFi, and this is working nicely (I can ping the MiFi from the router web interface).

The next step was connecting my PC to the router via ethernet cable, but now I'm stuck... The PC can ping the router, but not the MiFi (they're all on the same subnet). Since the router **can** ping the MiFi, I guess this is some kind of routing issue? Should I get a more "flexible" router, such as one with DD-WRT maybe? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

(For the record the PC is running Lubuntu 11.10)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution: installed [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato) on an old WRT54G I had lying around and configured its wireless mode as "wireless client".
Here's the guide I followed: http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/topic275631.html
I'll copy it here to avoid link rot:

```
Mi-Fi Gateway ip = 192.168.0.1

SSID = Verizon

Linksys Router using DD-WRT firmware v. 24

Gateway = 192.168.1.1

Router Runs in Client Mode

Using Static IP configuration

WAN IP = 192.168.0.100
Subnet = 255.255.255.0
Gateway = 192.168.0.1
Static DNS = 192.168.0.1

Static Routing

Destination LAN NET = 192.168.1.0

subnet = 255.255.255.0

Gateway = 192.168.0.100

Interface = LAN&WAN
```

(the guide suggested DD-WRT, but I preferred Tomato because it's less scary :D )

Note that the MiFi was configured with WPA2 and Tomato doesn't support that in client mode, so I had to switch to WPA.